# How do I get the x- and y-coordinate values of points in UTM using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, utm

To get to know the size of the study area and how far objects are separated, I need to know x- and y-coordinate values.

Although the $x and $y of Field Calculator returned latitudes and longitudes, x- and y-coordinate values were not obtained when it was in Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM). I think it should be possible to get x- and y-coordinate values since more complicated calculations, i.e. latitudes and longitudes, are possible.

Answer (score 3):

Reproject the dataset (using "Save as ...") to UTM and use Field Calculator on the reprojected data.

Comment: If you enabled OTF projection does it still work in the Field Calculator.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. It worked!.
A few days ago, when I saved my file as UTM, it did not worked. But this time, I successfully got UTM coordinates.